# Can we center those divs "IE7 and up" with variable width horizontally without using inline-block?

Tags: css

Without:

- adding any markup element there;
- without using `display: inline-block;`
- without knowing the div width;
- no hacks. the code should validate.

How can we center those three divs horizontally, but making them **INLINE** ?

http://jsfiddle.net/mMPMh/

**Please note:**
The reason that I'm avoiding `inline-block`, lies on the fact that IE7 should behave.
Other rules that don't work on IE 7 should also be disregarded.

**Is it possible ?**

Comment: why do you want to use divs? why not not spans?

Comment: @pomaxa: Because inside those texts I will have other elements. So they should be block elements.

Comment: If you're worried about validation why you no use conditional comments? Be smart and override the validator, there's no way to achieve this on IE7 without using the hacks on my answer

Comment: Relating "smart" with "trickiness" is something that bothers me ;) Other, then that, I'm starting to believe, that, indeed, there's no way to make this happen with those conditions. So the answer to my question should be a clearly "No. That's not possible. Forget about it, or change one of your conditions." :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this - http://jsfiddle.net/mMPMh/10/

Or this - http://jsfiddle.net/mMPMh/14/ ?
This one works with IE7

As for hacks, it can be served using conditional statement like

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Or using this on your HTML (from HTML5BP)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

And serve the style like this :

```
.lt-ie8 #one,
.lt-ie8 #two,
.lt-ie8 #three {
    display:inline;
    zoom:1;
}
```

No hacks

Comment: that DOES use hacks for trigger haslayout on ie returning validation errors. I can't use hacks.

Comment: It's the best possible solution so far. :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

UPD:
After you update your questionyou can use for IE `display:inline;`, maybe it will resolve your issue?

---

Like this - http://jsfiddle.net/mMPMh/4/ ?

remove `float`, set clear, and give if you need height and width.

Comment: You might have noticed that I have already misread it like that ;-) No width setting.

Comment: The problem here is that `display: block` element has a known width of being wider than life, so the requirement to stick to block and be ignorant of width is tricky.

Comment: @pomaxa `display: inline` will not work because that will convert my elements to inline elements, while they should stay block elements. :(